# Spring boot 2.5.4 / Spring cloud 2020.0.3 netflix ribbon conflict

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

While trying to upgrade from Spring boot 2.0.3 to 2.5.4, there's an issue with the `RibbonLoadBalancerClient` class from the `spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon` dependency which implements the  `ServiceInstanceChooser` interface  from spring-cloud-commons-3.0.3.jar.

What is the right version of the `spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon`  to use with this configuration?
I dont see 3.0.3 version of the netflix depndencies available.

[image]

I'm getting above exception while running the app due to conflict of the dependencies.

### Dependencies after the upgrade.

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Srping Cloud | 2020.0.3 |
| Spring Boot | 2.5.4 |
| netflix-ribbon | 2.2.9.RELEASE |
| netflix-zuul | 2.2.9.RELEASE |
| netflix-core | 2.2.9.RELEASE |
| netflix-eureka-client | 3.0.3 |
| Spring Cloud Commons | 3.0.3 |

---

### Dependencies before the upgrade.

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Srping Cloud | Finchley.M9 |
| Spring Boot | 2.0.3.RELEASE |
| netflix-ribbon | 2.0.0.M8 |
| netflix-zuul | 2.0.0.M8 |
| netflix-core | 2.0.0.M8 |
| netflix-eureka-client | 2.0.0.M8 |

---

I see below issue reported on github, but the right versions of dependencies were not mentioned.

https://github.com/seata/seata/issues/3492

### EDIT

After disabling the ribbon loadbalancer using `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled: false` in application.yaml rest api Calls are working for

```
NIWSServerListClassName: 
com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 1000
```

But not working for

```
NIWSServerListClassName: 

com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
    listOfServers: gateway-servicelist.com:443
```

Is there any limitation on the type of NIWSServerListClassName that can be used with Spring Cloud Loadbalancer.

Comment: Spring Cloud 2020.0.x removed support for ribbon. You need to upgrade to spring cloud loadbalancer.

Comment: Is Feign client/Resttemplate supported with Spring Cloud 2020.0.x for making rest calls?

Comment: It is, but with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer used for load-balancing requests and not Ribbon.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek Is there any limitation on the type of NIWSServerListClassName that can be used with Spring Cloud Loadbalancer? Works with DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList but not with ConfigurationBasedServerList.

Comment: Those are from ribbon and therefore not supported anymore

Comment: Is there any reference documentation for Spring Cloud Loadbalancer? I can't find except for blog posts showing usage examples. I would like to read about all available parameters of Spring Cloud Loadbalancer.

Comment: You can take a look at these

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-load-balancer

https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/05/13/a-deep-dive-into-spring-cloud-load-balancer/